# how access a character of a string using the offset operator, and the string is in a vector of strings?

Tags: c++, string, vector

You can access a string like any array or container class, eg, someString[0]. I've created a vector of strings, and for each string I want to evaluate each character, eg, someVector[0].unamedstring[0]. How can I do this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0;  j < x[i].size(); ++j)
            {   
            if(isspace(x[i].[j])//this produces an error; how to access this character?
            {

//more code....
```

Comment: Note that this reference might become invalidated if you insert to the `vector`.

Answer (score 3):

`x[i]` gives you the string, then you want to index with `j` into that string. So you just do `x[i][j]`.

Your idea of doing something like `someVector[0].unamedstring[0]` is wrong because `someVector[0]` is the string itself. The `.unamedstring` would attempt to access a member of the string.

Comment: ok, so you saying I'm trying to use class syntax when I need to use 2 dimensional vector syntax. cool. thanks.

Comment: @user2904033 I think you're confused. `someVector[0]` gives you the first string object, which is of course of class type (`std::string` is a class). You then apply operator `[]` to that object. This operator does have a full function name that you could use instead: `operator[]`. That is, you *could* do `someVector[0].operator[](0)`, but that's not very pretty is it? Using the `[]` operator is a much neater syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. You can access it as you would a multidimensional array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0;  j < x[i].size(); ++j)
            {   
            if(isspace(x[i][j])//this produces an error; how to access this character?
            {

//more code....
```